# Is there a msbuild dry run option?

Tags: c++, msbuild

I was wondering if it was possible to have msbuild report to me the files that are going to be compiled for instance. Now I know that depending on your build, files can get generated/changed. But in my use case I'd rather just have an estimate of files going to be compiled and don't need an exact match. However I couldn't find any option for this.

Comment: Maybe -preprocess

Comment: It seems like preprocess is only for file imports, but I'm more interested in for example, which .cpp files in ClCompile msbuild thinks it will have to build.